# Error posted "Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 1 arguments"

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

```
=IF(H2>="A", "Kindergarten"),IF(H2>="B", "Kindergarten",
  IF(AND(H2>="C", "Kindergarten",IF(AND(H2>="D", "Kindergarten",
  IF(AND(H2>="E", "1st",IF(AND(H2>="F", "1st Grade",
  IF(AND(H2>="G", "1st Grade"),IF(AND(H2>="H", "1st Grade"),
  IF(AND(H2>="I", "1st Grade"),IF(AND(H2>="J", "1st Grade"),
  IF(AND(H2>="K", "2nd Grade"),IF(AND(H2>="L", "2nd Grade"),
  IF(AND(H2>="M", "2nd Grade"),IF(AND(H2>="N", "3rd Grade"),
  IF(AND(H2>="O", "3rd Grade"),IF(AND(H2>="P", "3rd Grade"),
  IF(AND(H2>="Q", "4th Grade"),IF(AND(H2>="R", "4th Grade"),
  IF(AND(H2>="S", "4th Grade"),IF(AND(H2>="T", "5th Grade"),
  IF(AND(H2>="U", "5th Grade"),IF(AND(H2>="V", "5th Grade"),
  IF(AND(H2>="W", "6th Grade"),IF(AND(H2>="X", "6th Grade"),
  IF(AND(H2>="Y", "6th Grade"),IF(AND(H2>="Z", "7th & 8th Grade"),
  IF(AND(H2>="Z+", "High School/Adult"))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Formula confirms based on input data

Comment: May I know what this formula is about, it returns me all `Kindergarten` there is no sample data shown with expected returns, when removing all the `brackets` and `AND()`, not getting actually? No explanation no reproducible examples. Will you please take some time to edit the post and show us. Also confirm whether you are using `Excel` or `Google-Sheets`

Comment: You're right, almost anything you put in H2 will be greater than or equal to "A" so you will generally get Kindergarten. I will edit out the > from my answer, but that's only a guess.

Comment: @TomSharpe Sir, I wanted to comment you back, on your answer post, but then i thought its not your mistake its OP who has not given us enough information, so that said, by OPs logic your answer is correct hence voted up.

Answer (score 2):

You could get it to work by taking out redundant AND's and brackets like this:

```
=IF(H2>="A","Kindergarten",IF(H2>="B","Kindergarten",IF(H2>="C","Kindergarten",IF(H2>="D","Kindergarten",IF(H2>="E","1st",IF(H2>="F","1st Grade",IF(H2>="G","1st Grade",IF(H2>="H","1st Grade",IF(H2>="I","1st Grade",IF(H2>="J","1st Grade",IF(H2>="K","2nd Grade",IF(H2>="L","2nd Grade",IF(H2>="M","2nd Grade",IF(H2>="N","3rd Grade",IF(H2>="O","3rd Grade",IF(H2>="P","3rd Grade",IF(H2>="Q","4th Grade",IF(H2>="R","4th Grade",IF(H2>="S","4th Grade",IF(H2>="T","5th Grade",IF(H2>="U","5th Grade",IF(H2>="V","5th Grade",IF(H2>="W","6th Grade",IF(H2>="X","6th Grade",IF(H2>="Y","6th Grade",IF(H2>="Z","7th & 8th Grade",IF(H2>="Z+","High School/Adult")))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

or equivalently

```
=IF(
    H2 >= "A",
    "Kindergarten",
    IF(
        H2 >= "B",
        "Kindergarten",
        IF(
            H2 >= "C",
            "Kindergarten",
            IF(
                H2 >= "D",
                "Kindergarten",
                IF(
                    H2 >= "E",
                    "1st",
                    IF(
                        H2 >=
                            "F",
                        "1st Grade",
                        IF(
                            H2 >=
                                "G",
                            "1st Grade",
                            IF(
                                H2 >=
                                    "H",
                                "1st Grade",
                                IF(
                                    H2 >=
                                        "I",
                                    "1st Grade",
                                    IF(
                                        H2 >=
                                            "J",
                                        "1st Grade",
                                        IF(
                                            H2 >=
                                                "K",
                                            "2nd Grade",
                                            IF(
                                                H2 >=
                                                    "L",
                                                "2nd Grade",
                                                IF(
                                                    H2 >=
                                                        "M",
                                                    "2nd Grade",
                                                    IF(
                                                        H2 >=
                                                            "N",
                                                        "3rd Grade",
                                                        IF(
                                                            H2 >=
                                                                "O",
                                                            "3rd Grade",
                                                            IF(
                                                                H2 >=
                                                                    "P",
                                                                "3rd Grade",
                                                                IF(
                                                                    H2 >=
                                                                        "Q",
                                                                    "4th Grade",
                                                                    IF(
                                                                        H2 >=
                                                                            "R",
                                                                        "4th Grade",
                                                                        IF(
                                                                            H2 >=
                                                                                "S",
                                                                            "4th Grade",
                                                                            IF(
                                                                                H2 >=
                                                                                    "T",
                                                                                "5th Grade",
                                                                                IF(
                                                                                    H2 >=
                                                                                        "U",
                                                                                    "5th Grade",
                                                                                    IF(
                                                                                        H2 >=
                                                                                            "V",
                                                                                        "5th Grade",
                                                                                        IF(
                                                                                            H2 >=
                                                                                                "W",
                                                                                            "6th Grade",
                                                                                            IF(
                                                                                                H2 >=
                                                                                                    "X",
                                                                                                "6th Grade",
                                                                                                IF(
                                                                                                    H2 >=
                                                                                                        "Y",
                                                                                                    "6th Grade",
                                                                                                    IF(
                                                                                                        H2 >=
                                                                                                            "Z",
                                                                                                        "7th & 8th Grade",
                                                                                                        IF(
                                                                                                            H2 >=
                                                                                                                "Z+",
                                                                                                            "High School/Adult"
                                                                                                        )
                                                                                                    )
                                                                                                )
                                                                                            )
                                                                                        )
                                                                                    )
                                                                                )
                                                                            )
                                                                        )
                                                                    )
                                                                )
                                                            )
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

but it's far better to use a lookup table (or at least an IFS rather than an IF) for this sort of test than a massive IF statement.

**EDIT**

As @Mayukh Bhattacharya has pointed out, you get Kindergarten from the above formula for any string of letters. To exactly match each letter it should be

```
=IF(H2="A","Kindergarten",IF(H2="B","Kindergarten",IF(H2="C","Kindergarten",IF(H2="D","Kindergarten",IF(H2="E","1st",IF(H2="F","1st Grade",IF(H2="G","1st Grade",IF(H2="H","1st Grade",IF(H2="I","1st Grade",IF(H2="J","1st Grade",IF(H2="K","2nd Grade",IF(H2="L","2nd Grade",IF(H2="M","2nd Grade",IF(H2="N","3rd Grade",IF(H2="O","3rd Grade",IF(H2="P","3rd Grade",IF(H2="Q","4th Grade",IF(H2="R","4th Grade",IF(H2="S","4th Grade",IF(H2="T","5th Grade",IF(H2="U","5th Grade",IF(H2="V","5th Grade",IF(H2="W","6th Grade",IF(H2="X","6th Grade",IF(H2="Y","6th Grade",IF(H2="Z","7th & 8th Grade",IF(H2="Z+","High School/Adult")))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

but I'm not sure if that is OP's intention.

Comment: Or, something like but better is a lookup table as you have pointed out sir, `=IFS(OR(H2={"A","B","C","D"}),"Kindergarten",OR(H2={"E","F","G","H","I","J"}),"1st Grade",OR(H2={"K","L","M"}),"2nd Grade",OR(H2={"N","O","P"}),"3rd Grade",OR(H2={"Q","R","S"}),"4th Grade",OR(H2={"T","U","V"}),"5th Grade",OR(H2={"W","X","Y"}),"6th Grade",H2="Z","7th & 8th Grade",H2="Z+","High School/Adult")`

Answer (score 1):

You're using AND without using AND basically. AND() is used to have all of the arguments so for example AND(H2 = "I", I2 = "1st Grade") would be TRUE if both are correct, false if either of the arguments is wrong.
Secondly, you're not having any comparison in the second argument in the AND, it's just "1st Grade" and so on. So you start using AND in which the next IF is  for when it's True and so on and so on until the last AND to which you just close all of the brackets without a IF(argument,, value when true, [value when false]) composition.

> =IF(AND(H2>="A", "D">=H2), "Kindergarten",IF(AND(H2>="E", "J">=H2), "1st Grade",IF(AND(H2>="K", "M">=H2), "2nd Grade",IF(AND(H2>="N",
> "P">=H2), "3rd Grade",IF(AND(H2>="Q", "S">=H2), "4th
> Grade",IF(AND(H2>="T", "V">=H2), "5th Grade",IF(AND(H2>="W", "Y">=H2),
> "6th Grade",IF(H2="Z", "7th & 8th Grade",IF(H2>="Z+", "High
> School/Adult")))))))))

I'm not 100% sure there aren't any values that could be technically wrong (values that would belong between A & B for example, I'm not that knowledgeable about the nitty gritty stuff) but it gets the job done (shorter):

[image]